# Limiting thread numbers to run at a time

Tags: multithreading, perl

Consider that I have around 100 subroutines which I have to run using threads.
How can I limit all threads so that only 10 threads will run at a time? Can u give me a sample code.
Here is the sample code where i need to implement it

```
use threads;

my ($thr1) = threads->create(\&sub1,$parameter);
my ($thr2) = threads->create(\&sub2,$parameter);
...
my ($thr100) = threads->create(\&sub100,$parameter);

my $result;
for my $t(@threads){
    #print "$t\n";
    (my @getit)= $t->join();
    my $tmp = join '', @getit;
    $result .= $tmp;

}
print "$result\n";
```

Or Do you have any other method for it. Each subroutine will do different task.

Comment: How about [Thread::Pool](https://metacpan.org/pod/Thread::Pool)

Comment: The number of threads that can *truly run* in parallel is limited by the number of processors. How you can limit the number of threads you *create* in the first place depends on your architecture – in a boss-worker model, you simply spawn *n* workers and assign jobs via a queue.

Comment: @amon, That's only true if the threads are CPU-bound. A blocked thread doesn't use a CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use threads;
use Thread::Queue 3.01 qw( );

my $NUM_WORKERS = 10;

sub worker {
   my ($job) = @_;
   my ($sub_name, @args) = @$job;
   my $sub_ref = \&$sub_name;
   $sub_ref->(@args);
}

{
   my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

   my @workers;
   for (1..$NUM_WORKERS) {
      push @workers, async {
         while (my $job = $q->dequeue()) {
            worker($job);
         }
      };
   }

   $q->enqueue($_)
      for
         [ sub1 => ( @args ) ],
         [ sub2 => ( @args ) ];

   $q->end();
   $_->join() for @workers;
}
```

Comment: You used 1 subroutine here. Can you provide sample for multiple subroutine?Is `{ list of 100 jobs }` can be used for calling multiple subrotines?

Comment: I don't know anything about the modules he used but it appears obvious that you just have to add your different jobs via calls to `$q->enqueue($some_job)`. But you certainly should read up on the module before you use it anyways...

Comment: @wagh, Is each job a different subrountine? If so, you could pass the sub name as the job, then use `my $code = \&$job; $job->();`

Comment: @ikegami can you edit your answer to show atleast running 2 subroutines? I kind of stuck at this problem.

Comment: I already did: `my $code = \&$job; $code->();`. Just put the name of the sub in the queue. `$q->enqueue('sub1'); $q->enqueue('sub2');`

Comment: @ikegami how to pass arguments in subroutines here?

Comment: Put them in the queue. Pass them to the sub. See update.

Comment: @ikegami can u please explain the steps marked by #? in above script

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for Answer. I tried in my script But came up with another problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22633862/threadqueue-return-nothing)

Comment: Re "What arguements 'worker' taking?", Whatever you want, which is a reference to an array containing subroutine name and some args for that subroutine.

Comment: Re "how $sub_name came?" From the array referenced by `$job`.

Comment: Re "What are we doing with @args", Passing them as arguments